# queue programming in Java does not update the queue

Tags: java

I want to program a enqueue(elem) in Java, so I have programmed the following modules:

```
public class Node{
    public int e;
    Node next;
    public Node(int e){
        this.e=e;
    }
}
```

and now I want to use a Linked List to store my elements, so I made a class with a enqueue() function like this:

```
 public class Queue{
        Node q;        //represents a queue 
        Node first;
         public void enqueue(int n){
            Node t=new Node(n);  //represents a temporal node
            if(q==null){
                first=t;
            }
            else{
                t.next=first;
                t=first;
            }
            q=t;  //to store the node into the queue
        }
}
```

but when I want to print the elements of my queue:

```
 public void print(){
            Node current=first;
            while (current!=null){
                System.out.println(current.e);
                current=current.next;
            }
        }
```

it only prints me the first element that I enter, for example if I put 10,20,30,40 it only prints 10. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `q` should be your queue tail?

Comment: I don't see how your print routine works.  How are you updating current?  And next isn't being used.

Comment: the first thing you are doing wrong is unclear identifiers. Is "q" "lastNode"? Is "t" "newLastNode"?

Comment: @michalk not really, q represents my queue in the form of a linked list

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov, thanks for pinpointing those errors I made when translating my code; now I have fixed them

Comment: I think that for a queue you should store two pointers - one for head and one for tail.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for the class Queue should be the below. The node **first** will be the first element and **q** will be the last element.

```
public class Queue{
    Node q;
    Node first;
     public void enqueue(int n){
        Node t=new Node(n);
        if(q==null){
            first=t;
        }
        else{
            q.next=t;
        }
        q=t;
    }
     public void print(){
         Node current=first;
         while (current!=null){
             System.out.println(current.e);
             current = current.next;
         }
     }
}
```